# Icon or text to un-sync/revert changes

Tags: icons

In the context of file management across multiple devices-

I would like to provide users with option to "un-sync" or revert synced changes that where made on other devices. The syncing is done automatically, so there currently isn't an icon associated with that function. But the un-sync will be done manually...

Should I just use a text button rather than an Icon? I believe this would help preserve clarity

[common sync icons](https://www.google.ca/search?q=sync%20icon&es_sm=122&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ei=W2qtU6KYH8vLsASh9oHACw&ved=0CB0QsAQ&biw=1920&bih=955)

Comment: Why not use both an icon and text? The problem with icons is unless they are extremely common like the save floppy disk icon or wireless signal indicator icon may not be easily recognized by you audience.

Answer (score 1):

Icon + text for maximum clarity as @Kane says, and for the icon you could go with perhaps the easiest way of indicating "un-": put a very clear slash or cross on top of it.

Answer (score 0):

I've ran into the same terminology set of sync, un-sync, re-sync in a past project. We use the standard double arrow in a circle icon for "sync" and "re-sync", the same icon modified with a diagonal slash across it for "un-sync".

We show the icon next to the "sync" / "un-sync" text. Also put in a tooltip to clarify what "un-sync" and "re-sync".